# The best way to assemble Swagger documentation from multiple REST endpoints

Tags: java, rest, documentation, swagger

I'm working on a project which consists of multiple separated REST applications.
Each application has its own autogenerated by Swagger JSON specification, and attached swagger-ui module with appropriate documentation displayed.

The problem is that to find out some specific REST we need to iterate over all REST applications manually and check if it has the desired endpoint.

We decided to assemble all documentation in a single place and furthermore it should be done automatically, as RESTs often change and it's really painful to sync up all the documentation manually.

So, I'd like to ask, is there any tool which provides some API to allow easy registration of Swagger endpoints and displaying them all in a single place?

**Edit:**

I found that several API Management platforms like "Amazon API Gateway" can import Swagger specification and show appropriate documentation. But it's really huge system and I don't think that it makes sense to use it only for documentation purpose.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Swagger on the server side just exposes a `{war}/api-docs` endpoint for a single application/war. Unfortunately there is no way to put them all together out of the box as it would depend a lot of your application specifics. However, it should be fairly straight forward to note every application as it is loading and write down the war name. Since you also have access to the static HTML files you can easily override the UI to do what you need it to do. In this case you need it to

- hit a custom web service that lists all the applications e.g., `{apps:[users, animals, core]}`
- fetch the data from the known applications instead of having the user fill in  the information

You really have some flexibility here on the UI to create a new landing page or instead just simply override the Swagger text box to be a dropdown that fills in the application etc.